# Schema comparison script - IBM DB2 - including Tablespace (and everything)

Tags: sql, db2

At one point, many years ago - in a different lifetime, it seems - I had an SQL script which would compare absolutely every known attribute of two databases (Table definitions, indexes definitions, view definitions, SPs, etc), and report the difference.  This was back in the early 1990s, when finding information about such things wasn't quite as easy as it is now.

Then I moved on to other things, and lost that script.

Now, to my surprise, I cannot find any example of such functionality anywhere on the Inter-tubes.  Instead I find tools for sale in which even the "premium" edition of the tools is deficient in its scope of reporting on such diffs.

I really don't want to have to work through all that process again.

Does anyone know where I might find such a script for DB2 ?

Comment: db2look on both databases and a (semantic) diff...?

Comment: Did you try to compare with IBM Data Studio ?

Comment: I developed an open source library called Sentinel -- that can run from maven -- to take structure snapshots for this exact reason and then compares with a live database (or another snapshot) and informs the differences. So far it's functionality it decently complete, and works for Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server, MariaDB. I should document it. Sigh. If you know how to use maven and are interested, let me know; maybe it's a good opportunity to document it.

Comment: I wrrote a small parser for migrating from iso8859-1 to utf8 a couple of years ago. Probably not complete, but handled everything I needed at the time. It outputs the ddl in topological order. You may be able to adopt it to your needs:https://github.com/lelle1234/Db2Utils/